# Ruby Hash.has_key? returning false for the first key on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, hash, yaml

I'm having a weird issue with Ruby hashes on windows. I'm loading the following YAML file and parsing it as a hash:

```
tasks:
  - clone_skeleton, <skeleton_path>
  - summit_capify, <skeleton_path>
```

I'm using YAML.load() to load the file into a hash. If I print out hash.keys tasks is listed as a key but if I do hash.has_key?("tasks") I get back false. However if I change the yaml to this

```
directory_structure: 
tasks:
  - clone_skeleton, <skeleton_path>
  - summit_capify, <skeleton_path>
```

hash.has_key?("tasks") returns true but hash.has_key?("directory_structure") returns false. I haven't tested in Linux but I don't seem to be having this problem on OS X, just Windows. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and have tested in Cygwin and using the standard command prompt.

I don't know if this is a ruby bug, a problem with my YAML or something else.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Looks like this is fixed in Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible the keys are Symbols and not Strings?  Trying `has_key?(:tasks)`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get a notification about your reply. Unfortunately I'm now off for a week and not going to have access to a windows machine to test this on but I've tried it on the mac to see if it works there and has_key?(:tasks) returns false so I'm thinking probably not. Of course if it does work on windows I've got some really confusing issues to deal with! Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Ok, I'm back on windows now and I've given this a try but still no luck I'm afraid. Checked it on cygwin and normal windows command prompt. Should probably point out that they are using seperate ruby installs. Cygwin is using ruby installed through rbenv and ruby-build.

Comment: Ticking this as it's the only answer I've received and I'm hoping it gives you some reputation points for at least trying!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're debugging, don't do `puts hash.keys`, but do `puts hash.keys.inspect` - the latter indicates exactly what's going on.

Or you may want to do `puts hash.inspect`.

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try when I'm checking that 1.9.3 has actually fixed it. Thanks!